# hide a group of shapes with checkbox (JavaFX)

Tags: java, events, javafx, methods, event-handling

I am writing some code that has a UI and draws a rainbow. There is a checkbox that when clicked the rainbow will appear. When it is not checked off, the rainbow will disappear. There is a private class that is in charge of the action the check box does. Inside there is an if-else statement that states if the box is checked the setVisible for the rainbow is true, otherwise, it is false. What I am having problems with my code is that the box is not working. There doesn't seem to be any syntax errors anywhere so I am unsure of where the error is. I have not learned any other method besides setVisible.

This is my code below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;


public class Main extends Application {
    private Pane root;

    private CheckBox rainbowBox;


    private Rainbow r1;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        root = new Pane();

        r1 = new Rainbow(450, 425);

        rainbowBox = new CheckBox("rainbow");
        rainbowBox.setLayoutX(10);
        rainbowBox.setLayoutY(10);


        root.getChildren().addAll(rainbowBox);


        rainbowEvent showRainbow = new rainbowEvent();
        rainbowBox.setOnAction(showRainbow);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 650, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }


    private class Rainbow {

        private Group rainbowGroup;

        public Rainbow(int x, int y) {
            Ellipse circle1 = new Ellipse(x, y, 300, 300);
            circle1.setFill(Color.RED);

            Ellipse circle2 = new Ellipse(x, y, 290, 290);
            circle2.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

            Ellipse circle3 = new Ellipse(x, y, 280, 280);
            circle3.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

            Ellipse circle4 = new Ellipse(x, y, 270, 270);
            circle4.setFill(Color.GREEN);

            Ellipse circle5 = new Ellipse(x, y, 260, 260);
            circle5.setFill(Color.BLUE);

            Ellipse circle6 = new Ellipse(x, y, 250, 250);
            circle6.setFill(Color.PURPLE);

            Ellipse circle7 = new Ellipse(x, y, 240, 240);
            circle7.setFill(Color.WHITE);

            root.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4, circle5, circle6, circle7);
        }

        public Group getNodes() {
            return rainbowGroup;
        }

    }


    private class rainbowEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == r1.rainbowGroup) {
                r1.rainbowGroup.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                r1.rainbowGroup.setVisible(false);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Caution:  You have not initialized `rainbowGroup`, so it will always be null.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 1):

First, as pointed out by VGR, make sure you initialize `rainbowGroup` and put the ellipses in that group, and then put the group in the root parent. If you don't initialize `rainbowGroup` then you'll get an NPE. And if you don't actually put the ellipses in the group then you can't control their visibility all at once via said group.

Second, your event handler implementation:

> ```java
> private class rainbowEvent implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
>
>     @Override
>     public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
>         if (event.getSource() == r1.rainbowGroup) {
>             r1.rainbowGroup.setVisible(true);
>         } else {
>             r1.rainbowGroup.setVisible(false);
>         }
>     } 
> }
> ```

<sup>***Note:** Following standard Java naming conventions, classes start with a capital letter (i.e. it should be* `RainbowEvent`*). Though you may want to change the name as well given the current name doesn't really describe what it does (the class is not an event).*</sup>

Determines what to do based on `event.getSource() == r1.rainbowGroup`. Since you set the handler on the `CheckBox` that condition will *never* be true, thus only the `else` block will be executed. It also never queries the selected state of the check box. Changing the implementation to:

```java
// using lambda expression instead of nested class
rainbowBox.setOnAction(e -> r1.getNodes().setVisible(rainbowBox.isSelected()));
```

Should work for you. Another option is to use bindings:

```java
r1.getNodes().visibleProperty().bind(rainbowBox.selectedProperty());
```

Bindings, or otherwise observing he `selected` property, may be the more appropriate choice. That's especially true if the check box's selected status can be programmatically changed.

---

Note it's not often you actually need to query the source of an event. And the source of an event is always the node currently processing the event for which the handler was registered with. So, in your code, since you only add the handler to the `CheckBox` the source will *always* be the `CheckBox`.

Comment: propagating violation of naming conventions ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Well, technically I was simply quoting the code :p but I added a note to address the bad class name.

Comment: yeah,  _propagating_ == _quoting_ <g> thanks for the edit :)